# Create API to update record using id

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

**Using the id, i need to update/edit existing name, address, comment of the mysql database in nodejs, expressjs **:

```
router.put("/update/:id", function(req, res) {
  const { name, address, comment } = req.body;
  if (!id || !name) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send({ error: name, message: "Please provide name and id" });
  }
  dbConn.query(
    "UPDATE clients SET name, address, comment = ? WHERE id = ?",
    [name, address, comment, id],
    function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      return res.send({
        error: false,
        data: results,
        message: "client has been updated successfully."
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without posting your code your question will be removed.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez, i have posted my trial so far.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
const query = (query, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbConn.query(
            query,
            params,
            function(error, results, fields) {
                if (error) return reject(error);
                return resolve(results);
            }
        );
    });
};


router.put("/update/:id", function(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { name, address, comment } = req.body;
    if (!id || !name) {
        return res
            .status(400)
            .send({ error: name, message: "Please provide name and id" });
    }

    query("UPDATE clients SET name, address, comment = ? WHERE id = ?", [name, address, comment, id])
        .then(results => {
            if (results && results.changedRows > 0) {
                return res.send({
                    error: false,
                    data: results,
                    message: "client has been updated successfully."
                });
            }
            else {
                //handle no affected rows
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            //handle error
        })
});
```